# Subforms not scrolled fully up on open

Tags: ms-access-2007

This is a very simple problem I just can't seem to figure it out. When I open my form all of the subforms that I have on it are scrolled down nearly halfway. I do have headers on them but they are hidden and I have already tested to see if they are the problem. Thank you for your help sorry if this is so simple.

Comment: It is very difficult to answer this without either, preferably, a screenshot, or a better description. For example, do you mean that the subform records are scrolled, or the subforms themselves appear (on the main form) further down than they should be?

Comment: I mean the subforms themselves appear on the main form scrolled further down then they should be.

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to attach an image to the original post... try this http://i.stack.imgur.com/43W5r.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to find out what is causing this.

- Check the form header and footer sections for the main form and all the subforms. These are displayed in full (unless hidden) and they will reduce the height of `Details Sections` if necessary.
- Hint: Reduce the heights of these sections as much as possible. If this fixes the issue then you can progressively re-instate some of their heights.
- On the main form, check the occupied area of all the controls, particularly the subforms. `Ctrl-A` is a good way to check this (click on the form area before pressing this).
- Use `Ctrl-A` on the subforms as well to check these.
- Look for any controls that appear further to the right as well.
- Controls overlapping (even by a pixel) can sometimes cause unusual positioning.

I cannot be more specific based on the screenshot, but these are the steps that I would go through.

Comment: I'll try this out. Andy you have been alot of help with multiple problems I have had and I appreciate it. I just posted one more problem and I think it should be my last. Sorry that I had so many I'm new to access and am trying to learn it. It doesn't help that my first project with it was a pretty large one.

Comment: Thank you. I've found, and answered, your *last* question ;)